# No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)

Tags: server, ssh

I have a 16.04 server and I have a sudo account. I would like to create another sudo account and give it SSH access. I think I completed the necessary steps but still, the new sudo user is not able to access the server via SSH. After I typed username in Putty to log in, I get a "No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)" error.

I did read similar questions but I still cannot figure out what I am missing here.

Here are the steps I completed:

- Created user (`example`)
- Added the user to the sudo group.

  - groups example output: `example sudo`
- Change the current user to `example`
- Created RSA Key Pair (`ssh-keygen`)
- Copied the public key manually to the authorized_keys (`echo public_key_string >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

  - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABA... example@Web-Server (one line)
- I run this command: `chmod -R go= ~/.ssh`

  - -rw-r--r--  1 example example 655 Feb 12 12:22 .profile
  - drwx------  2 example example 4096 Feb 12 13:54 .ssh
- Permissions inside .ssh:
  drwx------ 2 example example 4096 Feb 12 13:54 .
  drwxr-xr-x 4 example example 4096 Feb 12 13:12 ..
  -rw-r--r-- 1 example example 406 Feb 12 13:06 authorized_keys
  -rw------- 1 example example 1675 Feb 12 13:00 id_rsa
  -rw------- 1 example example 406 Feb 12 13:00 id_rsa.pub

Please note that authorized_keys permission was: `-rw------`, I changed it to `-rw-r--r--`

*I completed these steps (everything) on the server.*

There is no "AllowedUsers" or "DeniedUsers" in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @user535733 I don't know what you mean. The new user's directory is `/home/example` I did everything on the server.

Comment: My misread, sorry.

Comment: Other Account's Putty is not configured to use public key authentication; the server is configured to require only public key authentication.

Comment: So what do I need to do? @waltinator

Comment: Find out how Putty configures which authentication methods it offers tje server. This is no longer appropriate for AskUbuntu

Comment: Can I create a user to use SSH without public key authentication? Because there are other users who can SSH into the server with putty that has default features (nothing configured on putty)